# Why is my field being null in jasperreport?

Tags: jasper-reports

Im creating a jasperreport field from a springboot + react application and i want to create a pdf with some static text and some text passed from database. Im doing a test using static text on my backend like this:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

params.put("riesgos", "TEXTO DE RIESGOS");

JasperPrint report = JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:risks.jrxml").getAbsolutePath()), params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

And this is my jasper file:

```
<title>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Texto de prueba estático - Lorem Ipsum]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="50">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{riesgos}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="50">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Texto de prueba estático - Otro párrafo]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</summary>
```

But the file is showing like this:

```
Texto de prueba estático - Lorem Ipsum
null
Texto de prueba estático - Otro párrafo
```